# How to push on my development branch on Github

Tags: github

I get an issue when I try to push on my development branch on Github. Actually, I forked the microscopejs repository to update some files...

Command :

```
git clone https://github.com/tonymx227/microscopejs.git
git add remote upstream https://github.com/tonymx227/microscopejs.git
git fetch upstream
// I updated some files using Sublime Text 2 here
git add . -A
git commit -m 'test'
git push origin development
```

Issue :

```
error: src refspec development does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/tonymx227/microscopejs.git'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't create a local `development` branch.

You only have the remote tracking branch `origin/development` after your clone.

Do first a:

```
git checkout -b development origin/development
```

Then:

```
git add . -A
git commit -m 'test'
git push -u origin development
```

Note: you don't need the `git remote add upstream` step.